# How does std::cout know where to print?

Tags: c++, cout, std

Why does a terminal window open when I run my C++ program, and how does `std::cout` know that it's supposed to print to that terminal?

Comment: `std::cout` sends characters to the standard output stream. The operating system arranges for the characters sent to the standard output stream to appear on the terminal (or be redirected to file, or pipe, or whatever); that part is outside the C++ language.

Comment: A terminal window only opens if you are attempting to run your program from within an IDE. In that  case the IDE will run your program (if its is not a native GUI program) by invoking an instance of a command line shell to start your program. The shell also serves the purpose of providing a place for console output and error messages to be directed by the program (and any input to be taken if needed).

Comment: Generally, part of the startup code (executed before `main()`) has the job of associating things like `std::cout` with something (a monitor, a window, etc).    That generally involves support from the operating system, which does have access to the context in which a program is run (e.g. it knows what command line shell or window launched the program, so can link output and input streams accordingly).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "*A terminal window only opens if you are attempting to run your program from within an IDE*" - not true. If the program is compiled as a console app, and is run from outside an existing terminal window, then the OS will create a new terminal window for it. That has nothing to do with IDEs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - true, I should have clarified how it was being run.

Answer (score 5):

Every operating system has what is called a "standard output stream", when you use cout, c++ just tells the operating system to print to the stream. The operating system is what figures out where to output it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler recognises that you're writing a console based application and provides a runtime environment suited to the type of program you're writing.

The type of application is usually selected when you start a new project but in older compilers, the console type was the only type that was available. MS-DOS and CP/M provided terminal services, upon which the command line interpreter like "command.com" would be the default program that could call other programs like "myCppApp.exe".

The terminal services included an input stream (what you typed at the keyboard) and an output stream (what was displayed on the screen). These were treated as special files which were readonly (cin) and writeonly (cout).

C/C++ provided access to these standard disk operating system services by way of cin/cout.

When windows came along, rather than use the text console (which you can still see on some computers when they boot up or in BIOS settings) people preferred to use virtual console windows that emulated the text console within a graphical user interface.

So its kind of a combination of the operating system providing a pretend environment and the compiler providing a runtime code based on the fact your building a console application.

Comment: The compiler neither knows nor cares that you're intending to write a console-based application. `std::cout` writes to the console, and the OS is responsible for making that work. If you're writing a GUI-based application you use a library that provides the appropriate function, and, again, when you make GUI calls the OS is responsible for making that work.

Comment: The linker will provide a different runtime environment for programs with WinMain() than programs with main() (linux and xwindows aside where xwindows is technically a console application)

Comment: The linker does what you tell it to do. If you link to code that works with a GUI, the OS is responsible for providing the supporting code. Again: it's not the **compiler** that knows what you're trying to do. It's your build system, and that's because you told it what you want. Don't get confused by pushbutton settings in an IDE; that's not the compiler.

Comment: Your splitting hairs here.

Comment: I guess I would also be wrong to say the compiler will do different things based on #defines and such like because the compiler doesnt even know theres #defines anywhere. Your splitting hairs. What has this to do with why the built program begins by opening a terminal window. Have a cup of horlicks.